# Need help to write view model code in android for data come from retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

I'am new to android and stuck in writing code for the view model, I don't know how to manage the data from repository and remoter server, here is what i have tried so far, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Repository Data Source

```
class RepositoryDataSource constructor(private val roomDataSource: QuranLocalDataSource,
                                   private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource) : Repository {

    override fun saveParaData(paraData: List<ParaData>) { roomDataSource.getQuranDao().insertParaData(paraData) }

    override fun saveSurahData(surahData: List<SurahData>) { roomDataSource.getQuranDao().insertSurahData(surahData) }

    //get Parah list from db
    override fun getParaFromDB(): LiveData<List<ParaData>> = roomDataSource.getQuranDao().getParaData()

    //get SurahList from dm
    override fun getSurahDataFromDB(): LiveData<List<SurahData>> = roomDataSource.getQuranDao().getSurahData()

    //get parahList from server
    override fun getParahListFromAPI() {
        remoteDataSource.getParahListFromAPI()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ result ->

                Completable.fromAction {
                    deleteParaData()
                    val data = result.body()
                    saveParaData(data?.get(0)!!.paraData)
                }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(object : CompletableSubscriber {
                        override fun onSubscribe(@NonNull subscription : Subscription) {

                        }

                        override fun onCompleted() {
                            Log.i("Repository onCompleted", "DataSource has been Populated")
                        }

                        override fun onError(@NonNull e: Throwable) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            Log.e("onError", "DataSource hasn't been Populated")
                        }
                    })

            },
                { error -> Log.e("ERROR", "{$error.message}") },
                { Log.d("getParahListFromAPI", "completed") })
    }


    //get surahList from server
    override fun getSurahListFromAPI() {

    }
}
```

this is my repository

```
interface Repository {

    fun saveParaData(paraData: List<ParaData>)

    fun getParaFromDB(): LiveData<List<ParaData>>


    fun saveSurahData(surahData: List<SurahData>)

    fun getSurahDataFromDB(): LiveData<List<SurahData>>


    fun getParahListFromAPI()
    fun getSurahListFromAPI()



}
```

this is my view model

```
class ParahViewModel :  ViewModel(){}
```

Comment: Follow the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).

Comment: You can get sample todo app by google [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp).

Comment: hi @Abdul Rahman Rathore i recommend you this course its awesome https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012

Comment: @Abu Noman thanks i did it